# Oracle SQL - How can I call the ODCI pipelined function using JSP

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, java-stored-procedures

The following is the exact implementation from 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/pipelined_example.htm#CHDHDHEE

Let's assume we have the following table deifinition:

```
CREATE TABLE StockTable (
  ticker VARCHAR(4),
  openprice NUMBER,
  closeprice NUMBER
);
```

Then, we've got the following types (A basic type as object and a type as table of it):

```
CREATE TYPE TickerType AS OBJECT
(
  ticker VARCHAR2(4),
  PriceType VARCHAR2(1),
   price NUMBER
);
/

CREATE TYPE TickerTypeSet AS TABLE OF TickerType;
```

Also, we have defined an ODCI type with its implementation in both SQL and Java Stored Procedure within database:

SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE StockPivotImpl AS OBJECT
(
  key INTEGER,

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCITableStart(sctx OUT StockPivotImpl, cur SYS_REFCURSOR)
    RETURN NUMBER
    AS LANGUAGE JAVA
    NAME 'StockPivotImpl.ODCITableStart(oracle.sql.STRUCT[], java.sql.ResultSet) return java.math.BigDecimal',

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCITableFetch(self IN OUT StockPivotImpl, nrows IN NUMBER,
                                 outSet OUT TickerTypeSet) RETURN NUMBER
    AS LANGUAGE JAVA
    NAME 'StockPivotImpl.ODCITableFetch(java.math.BigDecimal, oracle.sql.ARRAY[]) return java.math.BigDecimal',

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCITableClose(self IN StockPivotImpl) RETURN NUMBER
    AS LANGUAGE JAVA
    NAME 'StockPivotImpl.ODCITableClose() return java.math.BigDecimal'

);
/
```

Java Stored Procedure:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import oracle.sql.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import oracle.CartridgeServices.*;

// stored context type

public class StoredCtx
{
  ResultSet rset;
  public StoredCtx(ResultSet rs) { rset=rs; }
}

// implementation type

public class StockPivotImpl implements SQLData 
{
  private BigDecimal key;

  final static BigDecimal SUCCESS = new BigDecimal(0);
  final static BigDecimal ERROR = new BigDecimal(1);

  // Implement SQLData interface.

  String sql_type;
  public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException 
  {
    return sql_type;
  }

  public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException 
  {
    sql_type = typeName;
    key = stream.readBigDecimal();
  }

  public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException 
  {
    stream.writeBigDecimal(key);
  }

  // type methods implementing ODCITable interface

  static public BigDecimal ODCITableStart(STRUCT[] sctx,ResultSet rset)
    throws SQLException 
  {
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");

    // create a stored context and store the result set in it
    StoredCtx ctx=new StoredCtx(rset);

    // register stored context with cartridge services
    int key;
    try {
      key = ContextManager.setContext(ctx);
    } catch (CountException ce) {
      return ERROR;
    }

    // create a StockPivotImpl instance and store the key in it
    Object[] impAttr = new Object[1];
    impAttr[0] = new BigDecimal(key); 
    StructDescriptor sd = new StructDescriptor("STOCKPIVOTIMPL",conn);
    sctx[0] = new STRUCT(sd,conn,impAttr);

    return SUCCESS;
  }

  public BigDecimal ODCITableFetch(BigDecimal nrows, ARRAY[] outSet)
    throws SQLException 
  {
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");

    // retrieve stored context using the key
    StoredCtx ctx;
    try {
      ctx=(StoredCtx)ContextManager.getContext(key.intValue());
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ik ) {
      return ERROR;
    }

    // get the nrows parameter, but return up to 10 rows
    int nrowsval = nrows.intValue();
    if (nrowsval>10) nrowsval=10;

    // create a vector for the fetched rows
    Vector v = new Vector(nrowsval);
    int i=0;

    StructDescriptor outDesc = 
      StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("TICKERTYPE", conn);
    Object[] out_attr = new Object[3];

    while(nrowsval>0 && ctx.rset.next()){
      out_attr[0] = (Object)ctx.rset.getString(1);
      out_attr[1] = (Object)new String("O");
      out_attr[2] = (Object)new BigDecimal(ctx.rset.getFloat(2));
      v.add((Object)new STRUCT(outDesc, conn, out_attr));

      out_attr[1] = (Object)new String("C");
      out_attr[2] = (Object)new BigDecimal(ctx.rset.getFloat(3));
      v.add((Object)new STRUCT(outDesc, conn, out_attr));

      i+=2;
      nrowsval-=2;
    }

    // return if no rows found
    if(i==0) return SUCCESS;

    // create the output ARRAY using the vector
    Object out_arr[] = v.toArray();
    ArrayDescriptor ad = new ArrayDescriptor("TICKERTYPESET",conn);
    outSet[0] = new ARRAY(ad,conn,out_arr);

    return SUCCESS;
  }

  public BigDecimal ODCITableClose() throws SQLException {

    // retrieve stored context using the key, and remove from ContextManager
    StoredCtx ctx;
    try {
      ctx=(StoredCtx)ContextManager.clearContext(key.intValue());
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ik ) {
      return ERROR;
    }

    // close the result set
    Statement stmt = ctx.rset.getStatement();
    ctx.rset.close();
    if(stmt!=null) stmt.close();

    return SUCCESS;
  }

}
```

After all of this, in order to have a pipelined function that could be used to create a table of the aforementioned table type, we need to have a **ref cursor** and the **pipelined function itself**. I've put the ref cursor into a package.

```
-- Define the ref cursor type
  CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE refcur_pkg IS
    TYPE refcur_t IS REF CURSOR RETURN StockTable%ROWTYPE;
  END refcur_pkg;
/

  -- Create table function
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION StockPivot(p refcur_pkg.refcur_t) RETURN TickerTypeSet
  PIPELINED USING StockPivotImpl;
/
```

My question is just how can I call the StockPivot function in order to execute the JSP and display a table of the mentioned type.

I am expecting to get a result from a simple select which emulates a table:

```
-----------------------------
|  column1 |  column2 | ... |
|---------------------------|
| row_data1| row_data2| ... |
| --------------------------|
|___________________________|
```

I have tried to call the function like this, but it isn't working from **obvious** reasons (we need a ref cursor as a parameter):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(StockPivot());
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 Create function to return strong ref cursor.

```
    create or replace function getCursor return refcur_pkg.refcur_t  is
             c_tmp refcur_pkg.refcur_t;
            begin 
             open c_tmp for select * from StockTable;
             return c_tmp;
            end;  

SELECT * FROM TABLE(StockPivot(getCursor()));
```

Option 2. You can try cursor expression it also should work. [Cursor expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions005.htm).

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(StockPivot(Cursor(select * from StockTable)));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.